# How do I compare two linked lists in python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

first of all, my current code:

```
class linkedlist(object):

    def __init__(self, value, next = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def traverse(self):
        field = self
        while field != None:
            print(field.value)
            field = field.next

    def equal(self, other):
        while self and other and self.value== other.value:
            self = self.next
            other = other.next

        if self and other:
            if self.value!= other.value:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

My task is to compare two linked lists. If they are identical, the "equal"-Function should return "True", if not "False". The functionhead has to stay that way.

I tried to find a solution on my own for 3h and now i'm braindead. Can anyone give me some tips/help? I'm not the best programmer, so i'm sorry :(

Comment: What exactly is `self.value`, `self.next` and `other`?

Comment: Once you compared `self` / `self.value` / `other` / `other.value`, you could use recursion to compare the rest of the list.

Comment: What if one of the lists is longer? You then don't reach `return True` or `return False` so you return `None` instead. Have you got some test cases to share and how they fail or succeed?

Comment: @pschill: recursion is not going to make this any easier. They were doing fine with the iterative approach.

Comment: `self = self.next` is a path to disaster. Introduce a new variable. Don't override `self`. Not that it can't work - it can, but the code becomes a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @zvone: `self` is *just a variable* like any other. Inside a linked list traversing method, rebinding `self` is really not *that* bad an idea. No disasters will befall, at any rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You are using the correct strategy to traverse both linked lists and skipping any paired elements that are equal (your first loop).

Where you go wrong is that you then don't handle what comes after for all the possible scenarios. You know now that the two linked lists have a prefix of between 0 and N elements that are equal. You now have one of 4 options to consider:

1. `self` is exhausted, but `other` is not; `other` is longer so not equal, return `False`
2. `other` is exhausted, but `self` is not; `self` is longer so not equal, return `False`
3. `self` and `other` still have more elements, but the next elements for the two linked lists have unequal values. Return `False`
4. `self` and `other` are both exhausted, so have equal length. Their prefixes were equal, so the linked lists are equal. Return `True`.

You only handle option 3 right now. Given that 3 out of 4 scenarios lead to `return False`, it is easier to just test for scenario 4:

```
if not self and not other:
    return True
return False
```

or, as a full method:

```
def equal(self, other):
    while self and other and self.value == other.value:
        self = self.next
        other = other.next
    if not self and not other:
        return True
    return False
```